# jQuery regex ^= with number in between

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have elements like

```
user[0][foo], user[0][bar], user[1][foo], user[2][bar]
```

which are `names` of `select` tags.

I want use the `^=` operator to use `jQuery('select[name^=`(something)`')`
so that I can gather all the `foo`s together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there anything stopping you using the [ends with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/) instead?

```
jQuery('select[name$="foo\\]"]');
```

Note we're having to escape the "`]`" as it's a "meta-characters":

> If you wish to use any of the meta-characters ( such as !"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[]^`{|}~ ) as a literal part of a name, you must escape the character with two backslashes: \\. For example, if you have an element with id="foo.bar", you can use the selector $("#foo\\.bar")

http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors

Comment: Agreed... Ends with selector seems to be the right choice for this case... Thank you for the tip!